# how to stop php to display error before form submission

Tags: php, html

i have a this php script that send webmail:

```
<?php
session_start();

//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {    
    $sendto   = "info@davfubgroup.com";
    $usermail = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $content  = nl2br($_POST['message']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);

    $subject  = "New Feedback Message";
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

    $msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
    $msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>New User Feedback</h2>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Name:</strong> ".$name."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Phone:</strong> ".$phone."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "</body></html>";
}


if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "Mail Sent. Thank you we will contact you shortly.";
    echo '<center><p style="color:green">' . $_SESSION['errormsg']. '</p></center>';

} else {
    $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "Mail not Sent. Try Again.";
    echo '<center><p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION['errormsg']. '</p></center>';
}
```

the above code works very fine but my problem is it show **"Mail Sent. Thank you we will contact you**  when ever the page is loaded

here is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-grid">
  <form name="submitted"action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <div class="styled-input wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
      <input type="text" id="name" required />
      <label>Name</label>
      <span></span> 
  </div>
  <div class="styled-input wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
      <input type="email" id="email"required />
      <label>Email</label>
      <span></span> 
  </div>
  <div class="styled-input wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
      <input type="tel" id="phone"required />
      <label>Phone</label>
      <span></span> 
  </div>
  <div class="styled-input wide wow slideInUp animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
      <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
      <label>Message</label>
      <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="send wow shake animated animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" >
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

So my problem is how do  i make it to display error message only when form
is submitted.**please Note every thing has to happen on a single page**.

Comment: Fix the errors is the only correct answer

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Any reason you are suppressing the error output of `mail()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mail()` is outside the IF that checks that some data was sent to the form. Put it inside the if. Proper code indenting shows that in a second

```
<?php
session_start();

//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {    
    $sendto   = "info@davfubgroup.com";
    $usermail = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $content  = nl2br($_POST['message']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);

    $subject  = "New Feedback Message";
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

    $msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
    $msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>New User Feedback</h2>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Name:</strong> ".$name."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "<p><strong>Phone:</strong> ".$phone."</p>\r\n";
    $msg .= "</body></html>";


    if(mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
        $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "Mail Sent. Thank you we will contact you shortly.";
        echo '<center><p style="color:green">' . $_SESSION['errormsg']. '</p></center>';

    } else {
        $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "Mail not Sent. Try Again.";
        echo '<center><p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION['errormsg']. '</p></center>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a million, you solve my problem and i have given you a thumbs up (vote) but the problem now is that when i submit the form it does not show the any of the above message

Comment: That I am afraid is a different question

Comment: i known but please help me out,nothing changed just added the correction you gave,please have been on this for quite a long time